# Building Sakai 2.9.1 on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-6, sakai

I am using Sakai 2.9.1, Tomcat 7.0.59, JDK 1.6, MySQL 5.5, Maven 3.0.5 and Windows XP. The build of Sakai into Tomcat has been successful, and when I start Tomcat, I get a lot of errors and Sakai doesn't load. All environment variables have been configured, too.

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\opt\tomcat7021\webapps\access.war

Mar 12, 2015 12:41:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/access]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
Mar 12, 2015 12:41:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\opt\tomcat7021\webapps\access.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/access]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Mar 12, 2015 12:41:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive C:\opt\tomcat7021\webapps\access.war has finished in 828 ms
```

Comment: I am using maven 2.2.1 to build sakai and all the repositories are intact. I followed the installation steps on the https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=82249316  link.

Comment: Start by upgrading to a newer Sakai and Windows, you're begging for trouble by using old, unmaintained software for an Internet-facing application.

Comment: @reinierpost . WILCO.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Maven Build and Deploy (2.x - 3.x) page on the site you mentioned, in section 4.0 ("Install Maven 3.0 or later") it is stated that

> (warning) Maven 3.0 or later is the required for performing Sakai 2.9 builds.

This may be a starting point, since it seems that a class cannot be found while starting Tomcat.
Did you try using Tomcat 7?
Did you properly configure Sakay?

Comment: Upgraded from maven 2.2.1 to maven 3.0.5 and to tomcat7.